# Determine which control is not licensed in VB6

Tags: vb6

I have a legacy VB6 application that I need to make a simple change to until the replacement application is ready. When compiling, I get an error telling me that one of the controls I have included is unlicensed. IS there an easy way to tell which one? I have already gone through and run vbctrls.reg as well as, registered the ocx files, anibtn32, dbgrid32, gauge32, graph32, grid32, keysta32, mschart, msoutl32, spin32 and threed32.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Registering is not the same as having a license.  Those typically had a physical license file somewhere which allowed use from the IDE

Comment: Get the list of 3rd party controls from Project References. Then you can create an empty project. Drag one of the control from the list on the Form. Compile and run. In no error or un-licensed message pops up, remove this control and add the next.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to create a new sample project, and add one control at a time to that project. Run it for each one until you discover which control (or controls) are producing the error.